# Deploy Angular 7 to github pages

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-routing, angular7

I have a simple angular7 app that has only two routes the main the 'article'. It works if you test it locally but when you put on github pages it just loads the page's css. I deployed following the angular documentation at the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) and I also tried with the gh-pages tool. But none of them worked. If I remove my routes it would work.

This is the error I'm getting on the console.

```
1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'blogfolio'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'blogfolio'
    at t.noMatchError (main.5443131190bc79920d7b.js:1)
    at e.selector (main.5443131190bc79920d7b.js:1)
  ............

rodnorm.github.io/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

This is my code:

app.rounting.ts

```
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { ArticleComponent } from './article/article.component';    
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

export const routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: '', component: MainComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'article', component: ArticleComponent
    }
];
```

This is inside articleList.component.html

```
<div class="post-preview" [routerLink]="['/article']">
```

This is the app.routing.module

```
import { routes } from './app.routing';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If you guys want to check the whole code here it the [repo](https://github.com/Rodnorm/blogfolio) and here is the deploy [link](https://rodnorm.github.io/blogfolio/).

Comment: You possibly should be using `pathMatch: 'full'` for the empty ('') path and have a wild card path as your last one (to match non-existent paths), as you may see [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was happening!

Inside my /docs/index.html there was a base href that was given on the moment I ran the

```
ng build --prod --base-href <nameHere>
```

was not a relative url. I had to add // in this index.html file to the base href this is how it looks like:

```
 <base href="/blogfolio/">
```

This made it work. I know a good answer would be adding the '/blogfolio/' to the ng build href but that doesn't seem to work as well.

There's a PR about that [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26803#issuecomment-433866800).

Thanks for everything, guys!

Answer (score 6):

If you have router in your Angular application then it will not be available in GitHub pages and you’ll get a 404 page.

To solve this, you need to tell the server that what needs to be done when page not found, so make a copy of the index.html file and rename it to 404.html. This ensures that all the routes which are not found will be rerouted to the Angular router and it will handle this correctly.

Please refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015#for-apps-that-use-routing) for more info. Thanks!

Comment: Great point, that made me understand why the step in the tutorial on the official [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages) is necessary to copy `index.html` to `404.html`, although it feels a little bit hacky

Comment: This answer is useful, but the most useful part--the actual *fix*--is behind a link that is now dead. -1

Comment: I assumed that Angular official page will always be there and was no benefit of copying and paste from there so I just put the link, sadly its gone but please let me know in case of any issue, I'll try to solve that one.

Comment: In 404.html you need to update all of your <href> as per directory hierarchy on GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the `base-href`? I get a look to the repo and I didn't found it on project's configuration. Try to add `baseHref` in your configuration.

Just a fragment example of `angular.json`:

```
"outputPath": "wwwroot/dist",
"baseHref": "/dist/",
"deployUrl": "/dist/",
"index": "ClientApp/index.html",
"main": "ClientApp/main.ts",
"polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
"assets": [
    "ClientApp/resources"
],
"styles": [
    "ClientApp/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

You can read this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10736) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy `dist/index.html` to `dist/404.html`
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages

You can do in automatically:

1. add js script (e.g. scripts/patch-build.js)

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.copyFile('dist/index.html', 'dist/404.html', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('index.html -> 404.html copy failed:');
        throw err;
    }
});
```

2. Update build command in package.json:
   change `"build": "ng build"` to `"build": "ng build && node scripts/patch-build.js"`
3. Run `npm run build`. Done!