# Angular Routing in Github Pages

Tags: angular, routes

I've been trying to deploy a small Angular app on GithubPages, but im having some trouble with relative links.

For example, there is a link that opens in a new tab, works perfectly locally. But on github pages it returns an 'error404'.

```
  <a href="\assets\pdfs\geography\unit_1\economias_regionales.pdf" target="_blank">
     <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="pdf-icon">picture_as_pdf</mat-icon>Regional Economies
  </a>
```

I've already checked the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages) , and tried making a mirror 404.html but didn't work.

I've also tried the solution requested in [Deploy Angular 7 to github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621549/deploy-angular-7-to-github-pages) but it didn't work too, maybe im getting it wrong.

The full project is [here](https://github.com/fabichazaa/schoolsystem).

Any recommendations?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the leading `/` from the href, as this modifies what the link is relative to.

```html
<a href="assets/pdfs/geography/unit_1/economias_regionales.pdf" target="_blank"></a>
```

---

[This answer explains it fairly well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659501/8820824)

- Links with leading `/` are relative to the *root* of the web site. In your case, the link ends up incorrect:

  ```
  https://fabichazaa.github.io/assets/pdfs/geography/unit_1/economias_regionales.pdf
  ```
- Links without leading `/` are relative to your app's `<base href="">` tag. In your case, the link ends up correct:

  ```
  https://fabichazaa.github.io/schoolsystem/assets/pdfs/geography/unit_1/economias_regionales.pdf
  ```

You're seeing it work locally because in that case, the application happens to be served at the root of the web site.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to Hash based location strategy https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy