# 404 Error with Angular Routing on GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular app hosted in GitHub pages. I recently implemented routing, so my app has multiple pages. I followed the [documentation on routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route) to implement my `app-routing.module.ts` file (shown below).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'research',
    component: ResearchPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'publications',
    component: PublicationsPageComponent
  },
  // ... more here ...
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePageComponent
  }
];
```

The routing works perfectly as expected on my `localhost://`. When I publish the app to GitHub pages, however, the routing breaks:

- Clicking a menu link on the homepage: **works perfectly**.
- Attempting to navigate via URL directly to the home page: **works perfectly**.
- Refreshing the home page: **works perfectly**.
- Attempting to navigate via URL directly to any other page: **404 error**.
- Attempting to refresh any other page (after clicking the menu link): **404 error**.

**What is going on? Why does the app work as expected locally, but only sometimes work on GitHub pages?**

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523383/angular-routing-in-github-pages), but I have confirmed that my relative links are correct. I have also seen recommendations to switch to the hash routing strategy, such as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644587/angular-website-hosted-in-github-pages-does-not-work-if-i-refresh-in-any-route), but I want to stay with url routes because my url's need to be short and memorable (this is a personal website/resume/portfolio).

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer**

A concise answer can be found under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621549/deploy-angular-7-to-github-pages). Turns out this is a technical issue with the order of operations when it comes to routing in Angular. The official documentation has an answer to this problem under "[Deploy to GitHub pages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)", but it is poorly explained. TLDR; you need to make a 404 error page (and name it `404.html`) that is an exact copy of your app's *compiled* root page, and then put that inside of the output folder (such as `/docs`)from compiling your Angular app. DO NOT put it in your source code folder you compile from; the Angular compiler will not give the output needed for this trick to work.

There are more elegant work-arounds for other web hosting services, but you do not have the necessary access on GitHub pages for them.

**The Explanation**

Now, if you are interested in the explanation as to why:

Essentially, the Angular router lives within the root of your Angular app; it is bootstrapped into running after your Angular app starts. Your Angular app itself lives on the root page of your website.

Normally, when you request a url, the server gives you the page found at the url you request. Angular is "single-page", however; none of the other "pages" you are defining routes to actually exist. Angular is simply dynamically swapping the content within your Angular app to give the appearance of other "pages". The "routes" you set up on the Angular router are just mapping what content to swap which urls are *received by the Angular router*. That last part is key - and leads us to the order of operations issue.

Your Angular app, of course, lives on a server. When you request your app's root page, the server returns that to you. Then the Angular app and Angular router start up when you receive that root page. Well, to handle any of those routes, your Angular router needs to have *already been started*. The reason going to the homepage first, then clicking on links to the other pages worked, is because you requested your app's root page from the sever, it returned the root page, and then your Angular router started, **before** you attempted to navigate by clicking on the links. Once started, the Angular router can intercept the navigation requests and swap out the content based on the routes you defined.

When you try to request any of those routed urls from the server, however (which includes refreshing), the server doesn't see any other pages (since the pages do not actually exist), so it returns a 404 error. Even if you already have the correct "page" loaded, a refresh asks for that page from the server and overwrites what you currently have loaded. Your root page is never returned, so the Angular router was never started, so the navigation attempt just fails.

This is where the solution comes in. You can't change how any of this works, but you can basically trick the server into ensuring your Angular router starts no matter what. By duplicating your home page as the 404 error page, you are making another real page for the server to return; the page the server returns whenever there is a 404 error. Any route you request will now return your home page (the Angular app's root - whether returning the actual home page, or the 404 error page which is a duplicate of the home page). This guarantees that your Angular router starts - and now you can continue on clicking links as if it was a full set of webpages all along!